# Install Windows 7 from usb

Tags: windows

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and after a little work, I found out I want to have it dualbooting with Windows 7. After more work, the forums and posts say it's a good idea to have Windows on first, then add Ubuntu. So I got my copy of Windows 7 (known working) and made a bootable usb stick with it.

When I attempt to boot from the usb stick, I get a black screen for a couple of seconds, then Ubuntu boots. When I attempt to start install from Ubuntu by running "setup.exe" in Wine, it tells me it cannot find a place to store temporary files.

How do I use this stick to clear my hard drive and install Windows 7 so I can install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS afterwards?

Comment: You cannot install Windows while being booted to Ubuntu. You have to make sure that your USB device is bootable - check your BIOS settings for boot-order.

Comment: The boot order is not the issue, I manually select the usb stick to boot from first. That process worked when I was using a different usb stick to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

1 You don't need to wipe your hard drive - Windows will do it for you (and sometimes when you don't even want it to /sarcasm)

2 You will wipe the hard drive completely, install Win7 using the entire hard drive. Once Win7 is completely installed and all the patches and updates are applied, then turn the calendar page to November (it only seems to take that long after installing Linux)

3 THEN  boot from a USB drive, CD or DVD containing Linux and install Linux, which will automatically calculate how to resize the disk drive partitions for you.

Comment: My windows 7 usb stick will not boot. This is the problem. If the stick would boot, I would do just that.

Comment: Well, don't know if you can run Win7 from USB, but I have seen that you should be able to install Win7 from a USB. But, if that fails, just go back to the original media which Win7 came on, the DVD from Microsoft. You must install Win7 first and only then put Linux on the system.

Comment: I can't. I only have access to the .iso of Windows 7. And no CD large enough to burn it on to.